# Which of these reduction reagents would me most appropriate to yield this product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am very confused, I think using reduction would be a good start, but LiAl would go straight to an OH. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As you say*, the ketone must be protected.  Protect it. Any propagating naughtiness is irrelevant to the next step. 
2) Reduce the ester. Beat on it. 
3) Deprotect the ketone.

*Note that you begin with an alpha-ketoester.  In the old Morrison and Boyd that was a French joke.  LAH would have the same problem.  How the mighty have fallen.