# Reaction of a vicinal diol with acetone

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I have the first part correct; however, I can't seem to understand what the 2nd part's answer is. I realize the water leaves, but then what?

[image]

Comment: I changed the title of your question - completely. Don't get confused with the apparatus used to trap the water, look at the reactants instead. You have a diol and a ketone :)

Comment: That is an interesting product.  What is the reducing agent?  Absent that, how does it proceed to preserve the chiral center?

Answer (score 3):

There was this guy who recently [protected a ketone](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9166/challenging-reaction-question) in the presence of an ester. You might have heard about him ;)